# Model wont bind using json on Edit POST

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am trying to update a model using jQuery AJAX by passing a JSON to my controller action. 
I can see that the values are getting to my controller but some of my model properties like BackgrounColor and BackgroundImage is not updating. Why am I missing here.

```
    public PartialViewResult Edit(Header header)
    {
        // Get the record from the database

        Header oHeader = CreateHeaderObj(header);
        Header dbHeader = _headerRepo.GetHeader(header.Id);

        // Set the properties from the form
        // Todo : Needs better mapping
        dbHeader.Title = oHeader.Title;
        dbHeader.TitleImage = oHeader.TitleImage;
        dbHeader.BackgroundColor = oHeader.BackgroundColor;
        dbHeader.BackgroundImage = oHeader.BackgroundImage;
        dbHeader.ImageBackDefault = oHeader.ImageBackDefault;
        dbHeader.ImageBackClick = oHeader.ImageBackClick;
        dbHeader.ImageHomeDefault = oHeader.ImageHomeDefault;
        dbHeader.ImageHomeClick = oHeader.ImageHomeClick;
        dbHeader.Mode = oHeader.Mode;

        // Check if model properties are valid
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Model state is valid, proceed with update
            UpdateModel(dbHeader);
            _headerRepo.Save();
            return PartialView("_Display", dbHeader);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to update record.");
        }
    }
```

Regards,

Ryan

EDIT :
The function CreateHeaderObj returns a Header model with modified values like if the background is a valid hex, then prepend background-color: #. I can see that my backgroundcolor property is getting updated from #f9f9f9 to background-color: #f9f9f9 but it's not getting saved into the database. All I get is f9f9f9

Comment: There is absolutely no reason that only these two specific properties won't be bound. Please check carefully that you didn't misspell them on the client side.

Comment: Sorry, you're right the properties are getting bound. But before I save it to the database, I do some cleanup and my changes are not being saved into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to change some values from your view model inside a POST controller action you will need to remove them from the ModelState first. Because HTML helpers first look at modelstate when binding their values and then in the model.

```
ModelState.Remove("Title");
dbHeader.Title = oHeader.Title;

ModelState.Remove("TitleImage");
dbHeader.TitleImage = oHeader.TitleImage;

// ... you get the point
```

And you should do this for each property that has a corresponding input field and for which you modify the original value that the user entered:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Title)
...
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, never thought that was possible.